# Qual a forma mais eficiente de limpar uma lista (List) com C#?

Tags: c#, linq, desempenho, lista

Tenho um cenário aqui onde crio uma lista para checar alguns itens, e preciso limpar essa lista dentro do loop, e fiquei com algumas dúvidas em relação à performance

1. Devo checar a lista antes de limpar ? ( `.Any() ou .Count > 0 ?`) para não executar o `.Clear()` sem necessidade? Ou o If pode pior que o Clear ?
2. Mover a criação da lista para dentro do for? (creio que seja menos
   eficiente, criar uma instância do objeto a cada loop.)
3. Deixar como está, chamar o clear sem verificar se a
       lista há conteúdo.

   ```
       var gameIds = new List<int?>();
       var gameId = gameSession?.GameId % 100000;

       for (int i = 0; i < Messages.Count; ++i)
       {
           var message = Messages[i];

           gameIds.Clear();

       //.... mais código...
       }
   ```

Comment: Antes de pensar qual a forma mais eficiente de limpar a lista, escreva o código que faz o que precisa. Quando tiver esse código e ele funcionar, corra o seu projecto e utilize um profiler para saber se esse pedaço de código e sequer um problema. Optimizações prematuras são um problema porque achas que está a resolver um problema que pode na realidade nem sequer existir.

Comment: O código está pronto e está indo para produção, fui questionado aqui se seria melhor limpar essa lista ou não antes de realizar a checagem. Desculpe se não fui claro no conteúdo da pergunta. Obrigado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Deixar como está, chamar o clear sem verificar se a lista há conteúdo.

O método Clear já faz essa verificação, logo, codificá-la novamente não faria sentido.

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs

E como você mesmo disse, criar a lista a cada iteração é menos eficiente.

Comment: Excelente mestre! Era exatamente o que estava buscando, esse nivel de detalhe :)

Comment: [Aqui tem um teste](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gCcuMN) para você ver os tempos de cada possibilidade que você levantou.

Comment: Excelente compartilhar o código-fonte do `mscorelib`, ótima referência!

Comment: top demais , obrigado Pagotti

Comment: @Pagotti coloca uma resposta com esse link aqui, sera util para consultas futuras.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta que já foi dada, é possível usar a classe [`Stopwatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) para realizar testes de desempenho das possibilidades que você levantou.

Por exemplo:

```
public class Program 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {

        Medir(ListaCheia, "Lista Cheia");
        Medir(ListaVazia, "Lista Vazia");
    }

    public static void Medir(Action action, string Descricao) 
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        action();
        stopwatch.Stop();
        WriteLine($"Tempo: {stopwatch.Elapsed} : {Descricao}");
    }

    public static void ListaCheia() 
    {
        List<int?> lista = new List<int?>();
        for(var i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            lista.Add(i);
        lista.Clear();
    }

    public static void ListaVazia() {
        List<int?> lista = new List<int?>();
        lista.Clear();

    }
}
```

Coloquei um código [nesse link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gCcuMN) que pode rodar no .Net Fiddle para ver como funciona.